# Expresiones Regulares en peticiones AJax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, regex

Tengo una peticion REST que me devuelve un json con valores

```
{"Meta Data":{"1. Information":"Intraday (1min) prices and volumes","2. Symbol":"MSFT","3. Last Refreshed":"2018-05-30 16:00:00","4. Interval":"1min","5. Output Size":"Compact","6. Time Zone":"US/Eastern"},"Time Series (1min)":{"2018-05-30 16:00:00":{"1. open":"99.0000","2. high":"99.0500","3. low":"98.9100","4. close":"98.9500","5. volume":"2233252"}, ......
```

Lo pido de esta forma :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=*******"
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
});
```

El problema es que cada vez que me devuelve el campo esta con unos valores distintos ya qye la fecha cambia.

Preguntando en el foro me dijeron como representar los datos del momento. Pero los datos cambian asi que he pensado en añadir una expresion regular:

```
data["Time Series (1min)"]["^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])-\d\d\d\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]$"]["1. open"]
```

Pero no funciona, puedo añadir elementos de expresiones regulares de la forma en la que estoy haciendo, alguna ayuda??

Comment: por que usa `JSON.Stringify` en lugar de  `JSON.parse` en el `console.log`?. Lo ideal es que la repuesta de la petición llegue a su `script` en formato `JSON` y std lo parsee luego.

Comment: Y puedo añadir una expresion regular a la cadena?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes que mirar las claves de tu `data["Time Series (1min)"]` porque contiene mas cosas, te aconsejo algo asi:

```
var clavesBuenas = Object.keys(data["Time Series (1min)"]).filter(function(clave) {
  return (clave.test(/tuJsRegExHere/))
})
```

Con esto tienes un array de todas las claves que coinciden con tu expresion regular

Si quieres luego:

```
dataBienOrganizada = clavesBuenas.map(function (clave) {
  return { fecha: clave, dato: this[clave] }
}, data["Time Series (1min)"])
```

Mira la documentacion de Regex.test, Object.keys, Array.map, Array.filter, si lo necesitas